# Limit scrapy spider for certain number of requests

Tags: python, scrapy

I want my scrapy spider to close when a certain request limit is reached. I tried it but not working for me. It shows the input message again and doesn't break until the limit is reached.

Here is what I want:

- Input on the terminal if I want to limit the number of requests
- Continue under the limit is reached and break

Below is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

links_list = open('links.txt').read().split('\n')


class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'main'
    allowed_domains = ['www.yellowpages.com']
    start_urls = links_list

    def parse(self, response):

        try:
            limit = input('Do you want any limit? reply with [y - n]: ')
            if limit == 'y':
                limit_count = int(input('Enter the limit (Only a number value): '))
        except:
            pass

        for i in range(limit_count):
            i += 1
            if i == limit_count:
                break
        
            lists = response.xpath('//a[@class="business-name"]')

            for each in lists:

                link = each.xpath('.//@href').get()
                yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_links)

            next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "next")]/@href').get()
            if next_page:
                yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_links(self, response):
        link = response.url
        name = response.xpath('//div[@class="sales-info"]/h1/text()').get()
        address = response.xpath('//h2[@class="address"]/text()').get()
        website = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"website-link")]/@href').get()
        phone = response.xpath('//p[@class="phone"]/text()').get()
        email = response.xpath('(//a[@class="email-business"])[1]/@href').get()

        yield {
            "Link": link,
            "Name": name,
            "Address": address,
            "Website": website,
            "Phone": phone,
            "Email": email,
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the `CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT`.

> An integer which specifies the maximum number of responses to crawl.
> If the spider crawls more than that, the spider will be closed with
> the reason closespider_pagecount. If zero (or non set), spiders won’t
> be closed by number of crawled responses.

From the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#std-setting-CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT)

As far as controlling in terminal, you can use the `-s` flag, like this:

```
scrapy crawl my_spider -s CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT=10
```

**Now, looking at your control method:**

Let's say I just executed, and I inputed 10 for the `limit_count`.

```
        for i in range(limit_count):
            i += 1
            if i == limit_count:
                break
            lists = response.xpath('//a[@class="business-name"]')
            for each in lists:
                link = each.xpath('.//@href').get()
                yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_links)
```

In your first iteration (`i == 1`) lists will return a `list` of selectors (with links). Let's say `lists` returns 20 items. This means that in iteration 1, this nested loop will yield 20 requests, while `i` still equals to 1.  Your are not counting the number of request, but the number of iterations of the **parent loop**.

```
            next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "next")]/@href').get()
            if next_page:
                yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Now, each request for `next_page` will  callback the `parse` method in another scope, this means that they are not "aware" of each others the `limit_count` beign 10 and will procede to ask for their own `limit_count`. Here if you want to read more about variable [scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).

Finally your iterator will go for `i==2` (and so forth) and will repeat all that was done before. (Exactly as before, as `response` never changed.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried. It worked somehow but it doesn't actually crawl till the limit I gave. I put the limit 55 and it crawled 66 pages.
You can see the logs below:

scrapy crawl main -o dataset.csv -s CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT=55

2020-07-27 11:32:56 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (66 items) in: datasett.csv

Comment: `CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT` will count requests, not items. Even though this is strange, as your `parse_links` only yield an item per request. Are you running the same code you posted? I edited my answer to show you some problems in your loops logic.

Comment: Ok [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34535390/11326319) explains the pagecount discrepancies. I just learned about it.